# Header Stylesheet is not working for QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

I have following stylesheet for table.

```
QHeaderView::section, *[role="mockheader"]
{
    min-width:80px;
    background-color:#3949ab;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border:0px;
    outline:none;
    height:40px;
}

QHeaderView::section:checked, QHeaderView::section:hover
{
    background-color: #3949ab;
    color:white;
}

QTableView
{
    show-decoration-selected: 1;
    border:0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gridline-color:#454545;
    color: #FFFFF8;
}

QTableView::item
{
    border: 0px;
    min-height:35px;
    padding:5px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

QTableView::item:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 50);
}

QTableView::item:selected
{
    background-color: #3949ab;
}
```

Ideally it should paint header in blue color. it is seems unaffected. see attached snap.

[image]

*Left blue space is label, which i added for filling left space. Its not a part of table. Just leave it.

I am not able to figure out any problem in my stylehseet. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Which of the stylesheets does the problem generate?

Comment: I am not sure. What is wrong. Just I know same header stylesheet working fine for other treeView control but not working for this table

Comment: why use `*[role="mockheader"]`?

Comment: its for label which you can see left blue strip besides column headers.

Comment: basically there are some buttons down below that strip. I used this to cover space left by table. It is working fine.

Comment: I do not see anything strange, I recommend placing only the stylesheet that makes it change the background color of the headerview and see if it works, and then add one by one.

Comment: May be I am working on Ubuntu. It is taking ubuntu style

Comment: I have this same problem working with Qt on centos & fusion app style